# XSLT transformation behaves differently in Jboss Developer studio 7.1 and junit fails

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, apache-camel, xslt-1.0

I have a xml and need to extract some part of the message.The namespace is getting removed when using Jboss Developer studio 7.1 default xslt processor,but it is creating the namespace when using online tools and altova.
Junit test is failing because of this.
Can you please help me.

Input:

```
<response>
    <esb-metadata>
        <user-id>Cube</user-id>
        <service-name>Pricing</service-name>
        <source-system-id>Cube001</source-system-id>
        <source-transaction-id>1234567</source-transaction-id>
        <environment>DEV</environment>
        <message-type>RES</message-type>
        <result>DONE</result>
        <correlation-id>123456789</correlation-id>
    </esb-metadata>
    <message-body>
        <rating-pricing-response xmlns="urn:company:esb:services:RatingPricing:v01">
            <account_final_rp_rate>10</account_final_rp_rate>
            <account_final_bpp_rate>5</account_final_bpp_rate>
            <account_final_te_rate>15</account_final_te_rate>
            <group1_base_rate>9</group1_base_rate>
            <group2_base_rate>7</group2_base_rate>
            <state_group1_factor>5</state_group1_factor>
            <csp_group1_table_value>45</csp_group1_table_value>
            <loc_age_factor>10</loc_age_factor>
            <loc_sprinkler_group1>15</loc_sprinkler_group1>
            <loc_ded_factor>145</loc_ded_factor>
            <loc_fire_calibration>654</loc_fire_calibration>
            <loc_Modelled_cat_factor>44</loc_Modelled_cat_factor>
            <account_final_benchmark_rate>6</account_final_benchmark_rate>
        </rating-pricing-response>
    </message-body>
</response>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:company:esb:services:RatingPricing:v01">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//message-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template to copy attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
<rating-pricing-response xmlns="urn:company:esb:services:RatingPricing:v01">
            <account_final_rp_rate>10</account_final_rp_rate>
            <account_final_bpp_rate>5</account_final_bpp_rate>
            <account_final_te_rate>15</account_final_te_rate>
            <group1_base_rate>9</group1_base_rate>
            <group2_base_rate>7</group2_base_rate>
            <state_group1_factor>5</state_group1_factor>
            <csp_group1_table_value>45</csp_group1_table_value>
            <loc_age_factor>10</loc_age_factor>
            <loc_sprinkler_group1>15</loc_sprinkler_group1>
            <loc_ded_factor>145</loc_ded_factor>
            <loc_fire_calibration>654</loc_fire_calibration>
            <loc_Modelled_cat_factor>44</loc_Modelled_cat_factor>
            <account_final_benchmark_rate>6</account_final_benchmark_rate>
        </rating-pricing-response>
```

Actual Output:

```
<rating-pricing-response>
            <account_final_rp_rate>10</account_final_rp_rate>
            <account_final_bpp_rate>5</account_final_bpp_rate>
            <account_final_te_rate>15</account_final_te_rate>
            <group1_base_rate>9</group1_base_rate>
            <group2_base_rate>7</group2_base_rate>
            <state_group1_factor>5</state_group1_factor>
            <csp_group1_table_value>45</csp_group1_table_value>
            <loc_age_factor>10</loc_age_factor>
            <loc_sprinkler_group1>15</loc_sprinkler_group1>
            <loc_ded_factor>145</loc_ded_factor>
            <loc_fire_calibration>654</loc_fire_calibration>
            <loc_Modelled_cat_factor>44</loc_Modelled_cat_factor>
            <account_final_benchmark_rate>6</account_final_benchmark_rate>
        </rating-pricing-response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explictly using `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` to construct elements in the result file, putting them in no namespace is correct. If you want namespaces retained from the input document, use `<xsl:copy>`. If you want the output in namespace `urn:company:esb:services:RatingPricing:v01` regardless of the input, add `namespace="urn:company:esb:services:RatingPricing:v01"` to the `xsl:element` instruction.